# How to rename generic sas variables?

Tags: sas

I imported a dataset with `getnames=no`

```
proc import out=dstest
datafile

...

run;
```

and got a bunch of `F1-F5` variables

Now I want to rename them

---

```
 data dstest (rename=(F2=newName));
    set dstest ;
    run;
```

Here is the error

`The variable F2 in the DROP, KEEP, or RENAME list has never been referenced`

---

```
data dstest ;
        set dstest(rename=(F2=newName)) ;
        run;
```

Here is the error

```
 Variable F2 is not on file WORK.dstest.
```

---

However proc print works fine

```
proc print data=tortdata (obs=10) ;  
var F2;
run;
```

Comment: This might help you http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/sas/code/renaming_variables_dynamically.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing inherently wrong with what you've posted, insomuch as the code should run:

```
data blah;
f1=1;
f2=4;
run;

data blah(rename=(f1=a f2=b));
set blah;
run;
```

However, if you're just renaming the variable, no reason to do a data step.  `PROC DATASETS` can handle this without going through the entire dataset.  This may not matter much if the dataset is small, but if it is large, this may save a lot of time.  Note that you can't run the above and then this, as f1 and f2 will be gone if you don't re-construct the `blah` dataset.

```
proc datasets lib=work;
modify blah;
rename f1=a f2=b;
quit;
```

Comment: Thank you . apparently it worked with my data step as you said . i checked it with `proc print` . But why when i double click on the table icon in the `Explorer` I still can see the  `F1 F2 F3 ... all these names` ?

Comment: @Buras You're seeing the variable _labels_, which are not the same as the variable names - they can be text with spaces and such.  `attrib _all_ label=' ';` can be run, in either PROC DATASETS or the data step, to clear all labels (which means you then see variable names).